# Javascript handling varied responses from ajax request, and response.length = undefined

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object

I have an ajax request that returns json. If there's one record it returns this:

`{"key":"My Value 1"}`

If more than one record is returned it is an array of objects:

`[{"key":"My Value 1"},{"key":"My Value 2"}]`

I would love to just have a loop that would handle 1 or many objects being returned, but when I get only one back, `response.length` is undefined:

```
      console.log(typeof response); //Object
      console.log(response.length); //undefined

      row = '';
      Object.values(response).forEach(function(val) {
        row += '<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>';
      });
```

The problem is that response.length is undefined, but there's one record that's been returned. I would think if there was one object returned, then the length would be 1?  How do I test for a single object and also handle multiples? I'm thinking there must be an easy/flexible way to do this?

Comment: Either change the code on the server to always return an array of elements, or just wrap the response in an array on the client if it's an object.

Comment: keep the response consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to fix on server. If not possible do

`response = response.length?response:[response];`

For example

```js
let response = {"key":"My Value 1"}
response = response.length?response:[response]; // force array if no length
tb.innerHTML = response.map((obj) => '<tr><td>' + obj["key"] + '</td></tr>')
  .join("")


response = [
  {"key":"My Value 2"},
  {"key":"My Value 3"}
];
response = response.length?response:[response]; // force array if no length
//console.log(response)
tb.innerHTML += response.map((obj) => '<tr><td>' + obj["key"] + '</td></tr>')
  .join("");
```

```html
<table>
<tbody id="tb"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think I'll fix it on the server. I was having it dynamically return a row or an object using active record but i'm realizing that is complicating things and I should just always return the same thing...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the type of the response, if it is an array **[`Array#isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)** will be true and using **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** we can reduce the string by concatenation.

Else if it is a single object we can just extract the key and form the string.

But **better to fix the backend API** to return an array every time. If that is not an option use the solution below.

```js
function generateTableRow(response){
  let row = '';
  if(Array.isArray(response)){
   row = response.reduce((acc, {key}) =>{ //using destructuring to get the 'key'
       return acc + `<tr><td>${key}</td></tr>`;
    }, '');
  }else{
   row = `<tr><td>${response.key}</td></tr>`;
  }
  return row;
}
let response = [{"key":"My Value 1"},{"key":"My Value 2"}];
console.log("If array sent");
console.log(generateTableRow(response));
response = {"key":"My Value 1"};
console.log("If object sent");
console.log(generateTableRow(response));
```

Comment: Why reduce? Why not map? I find the use of reduce when you have one to one result not correct usage

Comment: @mplungjan actually I was trying to accumulate the object values into a single string, so I thought of using reduce. Please correct me if I am wrong, but using map will result in an array on which I again need to use join("") to get the result. As OP wants the end result to be a string :)

Comment: Yes you are correct. I do not have a problem with a join as I show in my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Object.keys(response).length` instead of just lenght.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the response is array using Array.isArray(response),
If it's not array then create array using the response and after that iterate it.

```
const responseArray = Array.isArray(response) ? response : [response];
responseArray.forEach(element => { // do your thing })
```